# How do I combine 3 Tables in 1 Query

Tags: php, mysql

I need to combine 3 things in 1 query to represent it on graph table.

The 1st Query is to Find NetAmount2017
The 2nd Query is to Find Budget (2017)
The 3rd Query is to Find NetAmount2016

The 1st Query:NetAmount2017

```
SELECT sum(a.netamt) as netamt2017, b.store_name 
FROM site_sales a JOIN site_store b ON b.storenum = a.storenum 
WHERE a.busidate >= '2017-01-01' AND a.busidate <='2017-04-30'
GROUP BY a.storenum
```

The 2nd Query: Budget2017

```
SELECT
SUM(CASE WHEN c.busidate BETWEEN '2017-01' AND '2017-04' THEN c.budget ELSE
0 END) as budget,
b.store_name
FROM site_kpimthslsbgt c JOIN site_store b ON b.storenum = c.storenum 
GROUP BY c.storenum
```

The 3rd Query:NetAmount2016 (same with 1st Query, but different date)

```
SELECT sum(a.netamt) as netamt2017, b.store_name 
FROM site_sales a JOIN site_store b ON b.storenum = a.storenum 
WHERE a.busidate >= '2016-01-01' AND a.busidate <='2016-04-30'
GROUP BY a.storenum
```

As Far as i can only combine 2 Queries Only, does not know to combine 3 Queries. Here is my combination for budget2017 and netamount2017.

```
 Select x.netamt, y.budget, y.store_name
 from
 (
 SELECT sum(a.netamt) as netamt, b.store_name 
 FROM site_sales a JOIN site_store b ON b.storenum = a.storenum 
 WHERE a.busidate >= '2017-01-01' AND a.busidate <='2017-04-30'
 GROUP BY a.storenum
 ) x
 inner join
 (
 SELECT
 SUM(CASE WHEN c.busidate BETWEEN '2017-01' AND '2017-04' THEN c.budget 
 ELSE 0 END) as budget,
 b.store_name
 FROM site_kpimthslsbgt c JOIN site_store b ON b.storenum = c.storenum 
 GROUP BY c.storenum
 ) y
 on x.store_name = y.store_name
```

The Result i want should show in 1 graph that consist of 3 bar chart which are, Netamount2017, Budget2017 and Netamount2016. The picture below show the result, but the Budget for 2017 is show only for 1month, not the selected month which is i choose from Jan to April. This is the Query i get so far for combine 3 queries

```
SELECT
SUM(CASE WHEN a.busidate BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-04-30' THEN a.netamt 
ELSE 0 END) as netamt2016,
SUM(CASE WHEN a.busidate BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-04-30' THEN a.netamt ELSE 0 
END) as netamt,
b.store_name,
c.budget
FROM site_sales a JOIN site_store b ON b.storenum = a.storenum 
JOIN site_kpimthslsbgt c ON b.storenum = c.storenum 
WHERE c.busidate = '2017-01' AND b.store_region='$store_region'
GROUP BY a.storenum
```

If i do this below query, if give me wrong calculation.

```
SELECT
SUM(CASE WHEN a.busidate BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-04-30' THEN a.netamt 
ELSE 0 END) as netamt2016,
SUM(CASE WHEN a.busidate BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-04-30' THEN a.netamt ELSE 0 
END) as netamt,
b.store_name,
c.budget
FROM site_sales a JOIN site_store b ON b.storenum = a.storenum 
JOIN site_kpimthslsbgt c ON b.storenum = c.storenum 
WHERE c.busidate BETWEEN '2017-01' AND '2017-04' AND b.store_region='$store_region'
GROUP BY a.storenum
```

[image: Wrong]

Comment: Can u post your table structure

Comment: Have you try `union`?

Comment: never try and does not know to use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanked God! I have found the answer, to combine all my Queries into 1 Query.
Here is the code:

```
 SELECT x.netamt2017,z.netamt2016, y.budget, y.store_name
 FROM
 (
 SELECT sum(a.netamt) as netamt2017, b.store_name 
 FROM site_sales a JOIN site_store b ON b.storenum = a.storenum 
 WHERE a.busidate >= '$date1' AND a.busidate <='$date2' AND 
 a.storenum='$storenum'
 GROUP BY a.storenum
 ) x

 inner join
 (
 SELECT
 SUM(CASE WHEN c.busidate BETWEEN '$date111' AND '$date211' THEN c.budget 
 ELSE 0 END) as budget,
 b.store_name
 FROM site_kpimthslsbgt c JOIN site_store b ON b.storenum = c.storenum 
 WHERE c.storenum='$storenum'
 GROUP BY c.storenum
 ) y
 on x.store_name = y.store_name
 INNER JOIN
 (
 SELECT sum(a.netamt) as netamt2016, b.store_name 
 FROM site_sales a JOIN site_store b ON b.storenum = a.storenum 
 WHERE a.busidate >= '$date1234' AND a.busidate <='$date2234' AND 
 a.storenum='$storenum'
 GROUP BY a.storenum
 ) z
 on y.store_name = z.store_name
```

[image: Here is the final result]